# How do to access an ActiveRecord relation ship using a string name of the relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an active record class that looks like

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :audiobooks
  has_many :ebooks
  has_many :physicalbooks
end
```

I want to get/set the relations using the names. How can I do that?

A probable example of the operation I want to perform:

```
books =  [ :audiobooks, :ebooks, physicalbooks] 
books.each do |b|
  user[b].build(...)
end
```

How can I do this in ActiveRecord.

Comment: user.send(:audiobooks).build(...)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `send` method, like so:

```
user.send(b)
```